# Class is not abstract / Activity cannot be instantiated

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to make a function, that would react to swipe actions. But I have trouble with it.

When I remove the abstract keyword, it throws an error:
`Class 'dock' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member`
When I keep the abstract keyword, the app doesn't want to start with the error:
`java.lang.Class<kiwi.you.app.dock> cannot be instantiated`

dock.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.Toast

/* CODE */
abstract class dock : AppCompatActivity(), GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.dock)
        hide_bars()

    }
    /* slot swipe */
    private fun slotSwipe0A()
    {
        val intent = Intent(this, zeroA::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_right_out)
    }
    private fun slotSwipe0B()
    {
        val intent = Intent(this, zeroB::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in, R.anim.slide_left_out)
    }
    private fun slotSwipe1()
    {
        val intent = Intent(this, one::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_in, R.anim.slide_down_out)
    }
    private fun slotSwipeMinus1()
    {
        val intent = Intent(this, minus1::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_down_in, R.anim.slide_up_out)
    }

    private val swipeThreshold = 100
    private val swipeVelocityThreshold = 100

    override fun onFling(downEvent: MotionEvent, moveEvent: MotionEvent, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean
    {
        var result = false
        val diffY = moveEvent.y - downEvent.y
        val diffX = moveEvent.x - downEvent.x
        if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY))
        {
            // right or left swipe
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > swipeThreshold && Math.abs(velocityX) > swipeVelocityThreshold)
            {
                if (diffX > 0)
                {
                    swipeRight()
                } else
                {
                    swipeLeft()
                }
                result = true
            }
        } else
        {
            // up or down swipe
            if (Math.abs(diffY) > swipeThreshold && Math.abs(velocityY) > swipeVelocityThreshold)
            {
                if (diffY > 0)
                {
                    swipeDown()
                } else
                {
                    swipeUp()
                }
                result = true
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    private fun swipeUp()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe Top", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        slotSwipe1()
    }

    private fun swipeDown()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe Bottom", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        slotSwipeMinus1()
    }

    private fun swipeLeft()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe Left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        slotSwipe0A()
    }

    private fun swipeRight()
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Swipe Right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        slotSwipe0B()
    }
}
```

I know that abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but how can I run it without errors? That's why I'm here. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement  `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` methods:

```
class dock : AppCompatActivity(), GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    override fun onShowPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onScroll(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
(...)
```

**Tip**: point your cursor on top of 'class dock' then press Alt+Enter keys, it should show an option `Implement Members`

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But why do I have to import all of these methods, when I don't even use them?

Comment: Thats correct, it's because you're implementing an interface, so you must implement all methods, you can let empty those you'll not use

Comment: @NewOlder if you're not using all of them, then there is no point to implement GestureDetector.OnGestureListener interface, then you might want  remove it from your code instead of implemeting all members with nothing inside